# Features with High Cardinality ( How to Vectorize them?)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to run a machine learning problem using scikit learn on a dataset and one of the columns(feature) has high cardinality around 300K unique values.How do I vectorize such a feature. Using DictVectorizer would not be a solution as the machine runs out of memory.

I have read in a few posts that I could just assign numbers to all those string values but would lead to misleading results.

Has anyone dealt with such kind of a feature set.If so, how to vectorize it so I could pass it on to train a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`FeatureHasher`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher). It

> is a low-memory alternative to DictVectorizer and CountVectorizer, intended for
>   large-scale (online) learning and situations where memory is tight, e.g. when
>   running prediction code on embedded devices.